# Remove redundant xml namespaces from soapenv:Body

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I originally posted a question about why did the elements of my webservice return not want to deserialize. I found that the WSDL.exe interpretation of my message was not working correctly. Here's what I changed:

```
[return: XmlElement( "RequestResult" )]
        public errorObject[] InitiateRequest(string[] params, string responseURL, string transactionID) {
            object[] results = Invoke( "InitiateRequest", new object[] {
                    params,
                    responseURL,
                    transactionID} );
            return ( (errorObject[])( results[0] ) );
        }
```

to

```
[return: XmlArray( "RequestResult" ), XmlArrayItem( "errorObject", Namespace = "http://namespace/version", IsNullable = true )]
        public errorObject[] InitiateRequest([XmlArray( "Params" ), XmlArrayItem("Param")] string[] params, string responseURL, string transactionID) {
            object[] results = Invoke( "InitiateRequest", new object[] {
                    params,
                    responseURL,
                    transactionID} );
            return ( (errorObject[])( results[0] ) );
        }
```

If you read the unrevised or original versions of this, my apologies for the long ramblingness. Hopefully this has the keywords people need to find their errors. I'll mark it closed tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question and revised the question totally, to encompass what the actual issue was. I hope this helps someone else, but I'm not sure what keywords would help here.